# Given a list of unique discount codes, how to send each one only once

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, mongodb-query

I'm wondering the best way to solve this problem: given a pre-generated list of 500 unique discount codes for an e-commerce site, how do I ensure that each of the first 500 users that receive a discount code each receive a unique one?  The e-commerce site would be making an asynchronous request to a separate server with the list of discount codes stored in its database.  It's this server's job to make sure that it sends back each discount code only once, in chronological order as requests are received.

As this seems like a rather primitive problem, I wonder if there is a clever and elegant way to do this with a relatively low level of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DB has atomic transactions, this is no problem.  Just make a table `discount` with 2 fields, `code` (varchar wide enough to hold the code) and `used` (boolean), indexed by `used` and then by `code`.  Initially `INSERT` 500 rows, each with `used = false` of course.  Whenever a request comes, just `SELECT min(code) FROM discount FOR UPDATE WHERE NOT used`, and then `UPDATE discount SET used = true WHERE NOT used AND code = <that code>`, all inside a single DB transaction.  (The `NOT used` part of the update is not necessary for correctness, but may speed things up by enabling the index to be used.)

If contention is a problem (and I don't see how it could be for 500 requests, but maybe it somehow could be), then add an integer `id` field containing a unique integer between 1 and 500 to the table.  Then on each request, pick a random number `r` between 1 and 500, and `SELECT min(code) FROM discount FOR UPDATE WHERE NOT used AND (id >= <r> OR id + 500 >= <r>)`.  The condition in parentheses ensures that the search will "wrap around" to lower-numbered discounts if (and only if) all discounts >= `r` have already been taken.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to have a collection of your codes and remove items as you select them. Here is a simple example with [**`.findAndModify()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).

A basic collection example:

```js
db.codes.insert([
    { "a": 1 },
    { "a": 2 },
    { "a": 3 }
])
```

Issue a `.findAndModify()`:

```js
db.codes.findAndModify({
    "query": {},
    "remove": true,
    "new": false
})
```

Returns:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550caf3f7d9c3dc0eab83334"), "a" : 1 }
```

And the new state of the collection is:

```js
    { "a": 2 }
    { "a": 3 }
```

So as the document is retrieved it is removed from the collection preventing further selection. Since `.findAndModify()` is an atomic operation, no other request can see the same document and every request will get it's own unique response.